# Dokuwiki + Lighttpd - Lighttpd won't start, include file not found

Tags: lighttpd, dokuwiki

Had a DokuWiki install working on my old OS, after reinstalling it to fix a driver issue I can't get it to start anymore. Attempting to run the command **sudo lighttpd -f wiki.conf** produces the following:

```
2019-11-02 02:49:20: (configfile.c.1232) include file not found:  conf-enabled/10-fastcgi.conf 
2019-11-02 02:49:20: (configfile.c.1154) source: /usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl line: 2 pos: 8 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL) 
2019-11-02 02:49:20: (configfile.c.1154) source: wiki.conf line: 39 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)
```

I've verified that the file it's talking about exists. Its contents are as follows:

```
# /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/fastcgi.txt.gz
# http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ConfigurationOptions#mod_fastcgi-fastcgi

server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
```

wiki.conf is as follows:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_fastcgi",
    "mod_setenv"
)

server.document-root        = "/home/void/wiki/fey/doku"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/home/void/wiki/fey/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 244


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

fastcgi.server = (".php" => ((
    "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
    "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket"
)))
cgi.assign = (".php" => "/usr/bin/php")

setenv.add-response-header = ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=> "*")

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

error.log is empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running '/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl' and see what you get.  Does the script expect your current working directory (from which you execute the command) to be /usr/share/lighttpd?  If so, I'd file a bug with the Linux distro which provides the script.  (What distro are you using?)

Comment: Result of that command is

Comment: include "conf-enabled/10-cgi.conf"
include "conf-enabled/10-fastcgi.conf"
include "conf-enabled/15-fastcgi-php.conf"
include "conf-enabled/50-dokuwiki.conf"

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint 19

Comment: As stated above, that won't work if you're not in the correct directory.